# Is it possible to pass object as route value in mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm trying to refactor some of my code and i'm wondering if it is possible something like this:

This is part of my cshtml:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Vote", "Ideas", new { id = item.Idea.Id, pageMetadata = Model.PageMetadata, numberOfVotes = 2 })">
```

This is invoking action:

```
public ActionResult Vote(string id,PageMetadata pageMetadata, int numberOfVotes = 1)
```

And `PageMetadata` is my class.

When im debbuging in cshtml site `pageMetadata` is correct,but when action is invoking `pageMetadata` it's becoming to `null`. Do I some stupid mistake or all idea is wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Query strings are like dictionary : {key, value} pairs. Therefore you cannot pass your class objects in query strings.

But, what you can do, is to pass this the id for your model object and then use that id to load your object on server.

Right now, you are working on a wrong notion ! :-)

Comment: Can you show an example of how you would load the model object from an ID?

Answer (score 2):

One other option is to serialize / deserialize the object for example:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Vote", "Ideas", new { id = item.Idea.Id, pageMetadata =   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.PageMetadata), numberOfVotes = 2 })">
```

in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Vote(string id,string pageMetadata, int numberOfVotes = 1)

var pageMetadataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PageMetadata>(pageMetadata)
```

Note: this will expose your object properties to the browser and could add significant size to the webpage depending on the number and type of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Html.ActionLink method :

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-Send-Model-from-View-to-Controller-using-ActionLink-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: Can you offer further explanation of why the `Html.ActionLink()` method is preferred over e.g. the `Url.Action()` method previously proposed?