# MVC 4 - Url.Action - How can I pass all information on the form to the action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following MVC 4 code that renders images to a page:

```
@foreach (var photo in @Model.ImageList)
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("DeletePhoto","Listing",new { imageId = photo.ImageId })">
        <img src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto", new { id = photo.ImageId })" alt="" title="Click on the image to remove it" width="250" height="190"/>
    </a>
}
```

When the user clicks on the image, the DeletePhoto method is called on the Listing controller. I'd like to also pass to this method the model, with all values, the view is bound to. Is there a way I can do this? I'm still fairly new to MVC so I'm not sure the best way to do this.

NOTE: The view is bound to a model that contains quite a bit more information than just the images. The view is a data entry form, with the ability to include pictures. So, when the image is deleted, I want to refresh the form, and keep whatever information the user has entered so I can redisplay it. And, it's quite possible this information hasn't been saved to the DB yet.

Comment: Well, usually you just get the id, as you do, and get the whole model from a query (to your db) in the controller's action (using the id, of course). Any reason not to do so ? If you really want all the model's datas, you can pass all parameters via GET (argh), or include all in a form and use the click on your image as an input submit.

Comment: The reason I can't get the model from the DB is because it's very possible the user hasn't saved the model yet. Therefore, there is nothing to get. Perhaps using a form and using the click as a submit is the way to go here.

Comment: If the model hasn't been persisted to the DB, why not just pass the ImageId back in an API delete call asynchronously?

Comment: @RandyMinder well, if there's nothing to get, a null check in controller's action is enough, no (as it's a delete, if you have nothing to delete... do nothing) ? Something like `var photo = context.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == imageId); if (photo == null) blabla else context.Remove(photo);`

Comment: THere is nothing to retrieve from the DB. However, the user could have entered quite a bit of information on the form, that hasn't been saved yet, that I want to keep and redisplay to the user when the form is refreshed, after the image is deleted.

Comment: I agree with Chris.  Instead of posting a form to do the delete, just make an ajax call to remove the image from the db and then update your page accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend to read my similar question:
[Is it possible to pass object as route value in mvc 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938210/is-it-possible-to-pass-object-as-route-value-in-mvc-3)

In few words-no,you can't do it in that way.